# Pythonic Way to set Multiple Properties Based on another class

Tags: python, django, class, model, getter

Is there an elegant way to handle all `get` requests of a class when I just want to pass the `get` to another object?

This is a Django project where I have a Video model; the Video can be from different sites (e.g., YouTube, Vimeo, etc).  The model is generic and will grab the appropriate `backend` to parse the data (which will be `repr` differently depending on the site).  All Videos will have the same properties but I have a different `backend` to parse them correctly.  Here is the example:

```
BACKEND_VIDEO_TYPE = (
    (1, 'YouTube'),
    (2, 'Vimeo'),
)

class Video(ItemBase):
    video_id = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    video_type = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=BACKEND_VIDEO_TYPE)
    video_data = models.TextField(editable=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("video_id", "video_type")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Video, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for k, v in BACKEND_VIDEO_TYPE:
            if k == self.video_type:
                VideoBackend = import_string( 'video.backends.' + v )
                # load the backend that matches the video type and supply it with the data to parse
                self.backend = VideoBackend(self.video_id, self.video_data)

    @property
    def link(self):
        return self.backend.link

    @property
    def thumbnail(self):
        return self.backend.thumbnail

    @property
    def is_public(self):
        return self.backend.is_public()

    @property
    def duration(self):
        return self.backend.duration
```

I don't feel like this is the best way to handle this but I am too new to know what to look for.  AFter I identify which backend class to implement, is there an easy way to `return self.backend.property` without having to add each property that is in the backend?  The list is going to get rather long.  A generic `__get__` or similar?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override `__getattr__` on the `Video` class so that it fetches an attribute of `backend`.

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
    try:
        return getattr(self.backend, attr)
    except:
        raise AttributeError('No attribute named ' + attr)
```

`__getattr__` will only call if the attribute is not found on the `Video` object (e.g. it wouldn't call at all if the user asked for `Video.video_id`) so it's a neat way to extend the exposed attributes of the `Video` class. The downside is that it may not be obvious which attributes are available, or it may expose some attributes you don't wish to. You could get around this by having the `VideoBackend` class provide a list of allowed attributes.

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
    if attr in self.backend.get_allowed_attr():
        return getattr(self.backend, attr)
    else:
        raise AttributeError('No attribute named ' + attr)
```

Comment: I see - but it wouldn't show up as an available attribute on its own (like the ones defined with `@property` do in the shell or documentation)?  That's where the function would come in ... still, this could save some typing and re-typing since they are just a mirror.  This is the idea I was looking for.

Comment: Yes, your code editor wouldn't prompt you for the properties unfortunately.

Comment: If I am storing a list already, could I loop through the list on `__init__` and set the properties that way (thereby allowing prompting?)

Comment: I don't think so as that again relies on pure code at runtime. You would probably get what you want if you made `Video` inherit the `VideoBackend` class, but not sure if that suits your code.